# Text Format in Adaptive Card on Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

I want to display this Adaptive card on teams in a chatbot. The choices are dynamic coming from the flow and then I display them in the card. What I am doing is saving a choice object in an array of choices then calling the array from the card. In the title I would like to make some words Italic. but this is not working fine on teams. It is working fine on Emulator and Webchat.

This is how I am saving each choice in composer:

[image]

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're doing trying to mark up the formatting with an underscore ("_") is using 'markdown' formatting. Does *does* have some basic markdown support (as does this StackOverflow site), for instance as you can see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772) for basic messages, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#format-cards-with-html) for within a card (Adaptive and other card types). However, per this last link, it's not supported for *all* types of controls in Adaptive Cards. See the first bullet point in [this paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#format-cards-with-markdown).